# Angular 6 routing using typescript function

Tags: javascript, typescript, svg, routes, angular6

I am trying to route programmatically through a function because I need a way around when clicking a link (a tag) inside an svg (since routerLink) does not work.

So far this is what I have:

```
    <g id="MenuStub4">
      <path
        id="box"
        fill="#231F20"
        d="M1171.088,420.473c0,4.307-4.387,7.799-9.795,7.799h-94.15c-5.408,0-9.793-3.492-9.793-7.799v-8.936
            c0-4.307,4.385-7.799,9.793-7.799h94.15c5.408,0,9.795,3.492,9.795,7.799V420.473z"
      />
      <text
        transform="matrix(1.3982 0 0 1 1096.8799 419.4614)"
        font-size="11.582"
      >
        <a fill="white" (click)="navigate()">
          Blog
        </a>
      </text>
    </g>
```

And the ts file:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = "BrainToBytes";

  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  navigate(): void {
    this.router.navigateByUrl("./blog");
  }
}
```

App-routing.module.ts:

```
import { BlogComponent } from './blog/blog.component';
import { NgModule, Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [{
  path: 'blog',
  component: BlogComponent
}];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

I checked the path, even if I change it with "/blog" it still doesn't work

I am a noobie with angular, so I am not sure if I am setting up the routing correctly or something else is wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if your **app-routing.module.ts** represents something like this:

`const routes: Routes = [{
  path: 'blog',
  component: BlogComponent
}];`

if you are navigating through typescript try this:

`this.router.navigate(['/blog']);`

You cannot put a routerLink inside an svg, so don't try that.

Comment: Do you mean app-routing.module.ts? I ll put in what it looks like in the question above thank you for your answer I think you are onto something

Comment: I added it to the app-routing, also the [routerlink] won't work inside an svg "Can't bind to 'href' since it isn't a known property of ':svg:a'."

Comment: Ok I made it route, the actual link goes to http://localhost:4200/blog but the blog page is not displayed